# Customer redirected to other customer account in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.7.0.2. when customer want to login they are redirected to some other account. i try to find the problem but i don't understand from where is this problem. i think this problem is related to authentication manager. they didn't clear the session of customer, so other customer redirect to different customer account. 
This the session code:

```
class Mage_Customer_Model_Session extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract
 {
/**
 * Customer object
 *
 * @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
protected $_customer;

/**
 * Flag with customer id validations result
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isCustomerIdChecked = null;

/**
 * Persistent customer group id
 *
 * @var null|int
 */
protected $_persistentCustomerGroupId = null;

/**
 * Retrieve customer sharing configuration model
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Config_Share
 */
public function getCustomerConfigShare()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/config_share');
}

public function __construct()
{
    $namespace = 'customer';
    if ($this->getCustomerConfigShare()->isWebsiteScope()) {
        $namespace .= '_' . (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode());
    }

    $this->init($namespace);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_session_init', array('customer_session'=>$this));
}

/**
 * Set customer object and setting customer id in session
 *
 * @param   Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer
 * @return  Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
public function setCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
{
    // check if customer is not confirmed
    if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
        if ($customer->getConfirmation()) {
            return $this->_logout();
        }
    }
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->setId($customer->getId());
    // save customer as confirmed, if it is not
    if ((!$customer->isConfirmationRequired()) && $customer->getConfirmation()) {
        $customer->setConfirmation(null)->save();
        $customer->setIsJustConfirmed(true);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrieve customer model object
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    if ($this->_customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) {
        return $this->_customer;
    }

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    if ($this->getId()) {
        $customer->load($this->getId());
    }

    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    return $this->_customer;
}

/**
 * Set customer id
 *
 * @param int|null $id
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
public function setCustomerId($id)
{
    $this->setData('customer_id', $id);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrieve customer id from current session
 *
 * @return int|null
 */
public function getCustomerId()
{
    if ($this->getData('customer_id')) {
        return $this->getData('customer_id');
    }
    return ($this->isLoggedIn()) ? $this->getId() : null;
}

/**
 * Set customer group id
 *
 * @param int|null $id
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
public function setCustomerGroupId($id)
{
    $this->setData('customer_group_id', $id);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get customer group id
 * If customer is not logged in system, 'not logged in' group id will be returned
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getCustomerGroupId()
{
    if ($this->getData('customer_group_id')) {
        return $this->getData('customer_group_id');
    }
    if ($this->isLoggedIn() && $this->getCustomer()) {
        return $this->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    }
    return Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID;
}

/**
 * Checking customer login status
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isLoggedIn()
{
    return (bool)$this->getId() && (bool)$this->checkCustomerId($this->getId());
}

/**
 * Check exists customer (light check)
 *
 * @param int $customerId
 * @return bool
 */
public function checkCustomerId($customerId)
{
    if ($this->_isCustomerIdChecked === null) {
        $this->_isCustomerIdChecked = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->checkCustomerId($customerId);
    }
    return $this->_isCustomerIdChecked;
}

/**
 * Customer authorization
 *
 * @param   string $username
 * @param   string $password
 * @return  bool
 */
public function login($username, $password)
{
    /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

    if ($customer->authenticate($username, $password)) {
        $this->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $this->renewSession();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Authorization customer by identifier
 *
 * @param   int $customerId
 * @return  bool
 */
public function loginById($customerId)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $this->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Logout customer
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
public function logout()
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
        $this->_logout();
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Authenticate controller action by login customer
 *
 * @param   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action $action
 * @param   bool $loginUrl
 * @return  bool
 */
public function authenticate(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action $action, $loginUrl = null)
{
    if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }

    $this->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true)));
    if (isset($loginUrl)) {
        $action->getResponse()->setRedirect($loginUrl);
    } else {
        $action->setRedirectWithCookieCheck(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::ROUTE_ACCOUNT_LOGIN,
            Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrlParams()
        );
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Set auth url
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @param string $url
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
protected function _setAuthUrl($key, $url)
{
    $url = Mage::helper('core/url')
        ->removeRequestParam($url, Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSessionIdQueryParam());
    // Add correct session ID to URL if needed
    $url = Mage::getModel('core/url')->getRebuiltUrl($url);
    return $this->setData($key, $url);
}

/**
 * Logout without dispatching event
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
protected function _logout()
{
    $this->setId(null);
    $this->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
    $this->getCookie()->delete($this->getSessionName());
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set Before auth url
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
public function setBeforeAuthUrl($url)
{
    return $this->_setAuthUrl('before_auth_url', $url);
}

/**
 * Set After auth url
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
public function setAfterAuthUrl($url)
{
    return $this->_setAuthUrl('after_auth_url', $url);
}

/**
 * Reset core session hosts after reseting session ID
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Session
 */
public function renewSession()
{
    parent::renewSession();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsSessionHosts();

    return $this;
}
```

}

Please tell me how to solve this problem.